# TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters') at p.createGlobalParametersForArmTemplate

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I clicked on the publish option in the Azure Synapse Workspace, that is published the content to the main branch, however failed to create ARM templets for the workspace_publish area with below error. Request to post the solution.
Generating templates

> {"stack":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'parameters')\n at p.createGlobalParametersForArmTemplate
> (https://web.azuresynapse.net/app.292be03f144476ff.js:4:5609257)\n at
> E.
> (https://web.azuresynapse.net/polyfills.8a5c72108a0df94b.js:1:126084)\n
> at w.args.
> (https://web.azuresynapse.net/polyfills.8a5c72108a0df94b.js:1:146342)","message":"Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters')"}

Tried passing the default values for the database linked service and checked the all the available LS and storage connections, notebooks, and pipelines and any other parameters.